# Two sum leetcode clang

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, for-loop, function-definition

I practice in c language, here is the exercise:

> Given an array of integers nums and an integer target, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to target.
> You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.
> You can return the answer in any order.

**Example :**

```
Input: nums = [2,7,11,15], target = 9
Output: [0,1]
Output: Because nums[0] + nums[1] == 9, we return [0, 1].
```

Here my attempt:

```
/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int* twoSum(int* nums, int numsSize, int target, int* returnSize){
  static int  r[2];
    for(int i=0;i<numsSize;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<numsSize;j++){
        if(i!=j&&(nums[i]+nums[j])==target){
            r[0]=i;
            r[1]=j;
        }
    }
    }
    return r;
}
```

But Irecieve a wrong answer:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEc7A.png)

Comment: OT: _Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free()_ and you return a `static` array.

Comment: @DavidRanieri I also tried `int r = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`

Comment: You should use `int * r = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);`. `Malloc` returns `void *`.

Comment: @sagi Toda raba

Comment: Shouldn't `returnSize` be used?

Comment: Your answer is considered wrong because it is empty/size zero. Were you supposed to also set returnSize by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function definition does not satisfies the requirement specified in the comment

> - Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free()

Moreover the parameter

```
 int* returnSize
```

is not used within your function definition.

It seems the function should be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstration program below. I assume that any element in the source array can be present in the result array only one time.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/**
 * Note: The returned array must be malloced, assume caller calls free().
 */
int *twoSum( int *nums, int numsSize, int target, int *returnSize )
{
    int *result = NULL;
    *returnSize = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] + nums[j] == target)
            {
                int unique = result == NULL;

                if (!unique)
                {
                    unique = 1;
                    for (int k = 1; unique && k < *returnSize; k += 2)
                    {
                        unique = nums[k] != nums[j];
                    }
                }

                if (unique)
                {
                    int *tmp = realloc( result, ( *returnSize + 2 ) * sizeof( int ) );
                    if (tmp != NULL)
                    {
                        result = tmp;
                        result[*returnSize] = i;
                        result[*returnSize + 1] = j;
                        *returnSize += 2;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int main( void )
{
    int a[] = { 2, 7, 11, 15 };
    int target = 9;
    int resultSize;

    int *result = twoSum( a, sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a ), target, &resultSize );

    if (result)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < resultSize; i += 2 )
        {
            printf( "%d, %d ", result[i], result[i + 1] );
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    free( result );
}
```

The program output is

```
0, 1
```

Though as for me then I would declare the function like

```
int *twoSum( const int *nums, size_t numsSize, int target, size_t *returnSize );
```

Answer (score 0):

The brute force approach is very simple to this problem.

```
int* twoSum(int* arr, int n, int t, int* returnSize){
    int *res=malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    *returnSize=2;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if((arr[i]+arr[j])==t)
            {
                res[0]=i;
                res[1]=j;
                goto exit;
              
            }
        }
        
    }
    exit:
    return res;
}
```